# View History in TFS

Tags: tfs

We have created a New Team Project in TFS 2008. We want to merge 7 different team projects with this New Team Project and finally delete the old 7 projects.

A existing project is branched with a new team project. After this,we are not able to view the history of source project in the target (new) project view history. Please let us know, how to propagate the complete history from source project to target project.

I am new to this...I don't know whether I have stated the issue correctly or not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using the Rename feature to place the code under the same team project, rather than branching.

There is no UI for branch/merge history built into TFS 2005/2008.  You have to use the command line (tf merges) or 3rd party tools (e.g. Attrice Sidekicks).